# Laravel 5.1 View code result in syntax error, unexpected '')); ?>" ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Tags: php, view, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have this warning:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>   1/1
>   FatalErrorException in f042f5969df1fc17d22527840a4806ba line 59:
>   syntax error, unexpected '')); ?>"
>   ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)
>   in f042f5969df1fc17d22527840a4806ba line 59

I've tried to find the problem but still not be able find it. This is my code of `index.blade.php`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
`@extends('admin.layout')`
`@section('content')`
    <div class="row page-title-row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Posts <small>» Listing</small></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
        <a href="{{ URL('/admin/post/create')}}" class="btn btn-success btn-md">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> New Post
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">

        `@include('admin.partials.errors')`
        `@include('admin.partials.success')`

        <table id="posts-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Published</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Subtitle</th>
              <th data-sortable="false">Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach ($posts as $post)
              <tr>
                <td data-order="{{ $post->published_at->timestamp }}">
                  {!! $post->published_at->format('j-M-y g:ia') !!}
                </td>
                <td>{!! $post->title !!}</td>
                <td>{!! $post->subtitle !!}</td>
                <td>
                  <a href="{{ URL('/admin/post/'.$post->id.'/edit')}}"
                     class="btn btn-xs btn-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
                  </a>
                  <a href="{{ URL('/blog/'.$post->slug')}}"
                     class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
`@stop`

-------------------------------------------------------------line 59



`@section('scripts')`    
<script>
        $(function() {
          $("#posts-table").DataTable({
            order: [[0, "desc"]]
          });
        });
      </script>
`@stop`
```

Comment: What is on line 59 on the above mentioned file which can be found under storage/framework/views folder

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quote at the end of this `{{ URL('/blog/'.$post->slug')}}` so it will look like `{{ URL('/blog/'.$post->slug)}}`

Comment: i've removed the single quotes but it still not working

Comment: Try removing the quote at the end of this `{{ URL('/blog/'.$post->slug')}}` so it will look like `{{ URL('/blog/'.$post->slug)}}`

Comment: I updated my original post so you can accept that as the answer for future reference :)

Answer (score 0):

This is your error here

```
"{{ URL('/blog/'.$post->slug')}}"
```

The single quote after slug.

Comment: Great, would you accept the answer please, to close this question